# Redux store not connected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router-v4, redux-thunk

I am developing a Reactjs web application from scratch and encountered a tricky situation which i need help with. Whenever i navigate away from a particular url and navigate back, my redux store does not seem to be connected.

routes.js

```
const RouteList = () => (
  <main>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/abc/" exact component={withRouter(HomePage)} />
      <Route path="/abc/xyz" exact component={withRouter(XYZPage)} />
      <Redirect from="/" to="/abc/" />
      <Route component={Error} />
     </Switch>
   </main>
);
export default RouteList;
```

App.js

```
class  App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <div>
          <Header />
          <RouteList />
          <Footer />
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Header.js

```
const Header = () => {
  return (
    <Navbar expand="md">
      <NavbarBrand tag={NavLink} to="/">
        <img src={brandImage} style={{marginRight: "0", width: "40px", height: "40px"}} /><strong style={{color: "#457B9D"}} >Datum</strong>
      </NavbarBrand>

      <Nav className="mr-auto" navbar>
        <NavItem>
          <NavLink className="nav-link" to={"/abc/xyz"} >XYZ</NavLink>
        </NavItem>
      </Nav>
    </Navbar>
  );
};

export default withRouter(Header);
```

When i hit the NavLink which will take me to url: /"abc/xyz", it will take me to XYZPage.js

XYZPage.js

```
class XYZPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);

    this.state = {
      activeTab: "1"
    };

    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
  }

  toggle(tab) {
    if (this.state.activeTab !== tab) {
      this.setState({
        activeTab: tab
      });
    }
  }
  render () {
    return (
      <main>
        <div className="container-fluid pt-3">
          <Nav tabs>
            <NavItem>
              <NavLink
                className={classnames({active: this.state.activeTab === "1"})}
                onClick={() => {this.toggle("1"); }} >
                AAA
              </NavLink>
            </NavItem>
            <NavItem>
              <NavLink
                className={classnames({active: this.state.activeTab === "2"})}
                onClick={() => {this.toggle("2"); }} >
                BBB
              </NavLink>
            </NavItem>
            <NavItem>
              <NavLink
                className={classnames({active: this.state.activeTab === "3"})}
                onClick={() => {this.toggle("3"); }} >
                CCC
              </NavLink>
            </NavItem>
          </Nav>
          <TabContent activeTab={this.state.activeTab}>
            <TabPane tabId="1">
              <Row>
                <AAAPAge/>
              </Row>
            </TabPane>
            <TabPane tabId="2">
              <Row>
                <BBBPage/>
              </Row>
            </TabPane>
            <TabPane tabId="3">
              <Row>
                <CCCPage/>
              </Row>
            </TabPane>
          </TabContent>
        </div>
      </main>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(XYZPage);
```

Each of the AAAPage, BBBPage & CCCPage are components which needs to have some pre-populated dropdowns which i declared in my index.js below:

index.js

```
const store = configureStore();
store.dispatch(loadAAA());
store.dispatch(loadBBB());
store.dispatch(loadCCC());

render((
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>
), document.getElementById('app'));
```

loadAAA, loadBBB & loadCCC are all thunks

The configureStore() method is as such:

```
export default function configureStore(initialState) {
  return createStore(
    rootReducer,
    initialState,
    composeWithDevTools(
      applyMiddleware(thunk, reduxImmutableStateInvariant()),
    )
  );
}
```

To shorten this post i give a sample of my AAAPage as the others are of similar structure:

AAAPage.js:

```
class AAAPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = {...};
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {...}

  render() {
    [...]
    return (
      <Container fluid>
        <Row>
          <AAAInputForm
            // Data from Store is passed here 
          />
        </Row>
        {ChildComponent}
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

AAAPage.propTypes = {
  DATA: PropTypes.array
};

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  let DATA = [];
  if (state.AAAReducer.length > 0) {
    DATA = state.AAAReducer;
  }

  return {
    DATA: DATA
  };
}

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(AAAPage));
```

AAAReducer.js:

```
export default function AAAReducer(state=initialState.AAAList, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case types.LOAD_AAA_SUCCESS:
      return action.AAAList;

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

AAAAction.js:

```
export function loadAAASuccess(AAAList) {
  return {
    type: types.LOAD_AAA_SUCCESS,
    AAAList: AAAlList
  };
}

// thunk
export function loadAAA() {
  // A thunk will always return a function that accepts a dispatch
  return function(dispatch) {
    return apiCall("ALL").then(response => {
      dispatch(loadAAASuccess(response.data.AAA));
    }).catch(error => {
      throw(error);
    });
  };
}
```

initialState.js:

```
export default {
  AAAList: [],
  BBBList: [],
  CCCList: []
};
```

At this point i believe i provided enough background to my code. I followed tutorials when designing this redux store and I am not sure why when i navigate from "/abc/xyz" to "/abc" and back, or when i navigate to "/abc/xyz" from "/abc", my stores are empty although i called the loadAAA() method at my index.js. All the other pages are affected as well. However, when i hit "/abc/xyz" directly, my stores are connected and my dropdowns are populated. What is happening? Is it because of my lifecycle methods?

I am using react v15.6.2, redux v3.7.2 & redux-thunk v2.3.0.

Thanks for the guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only call `loadAAA` at the top level of `index.js`, which only executes once when your page loads. If you want to dispatch it every time your `XYZPage` page renders, put in XYZ's `componentDidMount`

Comment: Okay, will do that, but what is the reason for needing to do so? Doesnt redux store remembers the state or have i been misunderstanding how the redux store work?

Answer (score 0):

@AKJ - @Andy Ray said it correctly, but I'll like to add that `componentDidMount` is the best place to load `async` calls, as it is called after render and about `Store` redux store keeps data until you refresh the page after refresh redux store is reinitialized, if you need store the data after refresh try [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist)

Comment: If that is the case, then are we suggesting that mapStateToProps should only work for states that are non-async calls? I always assumed that when i made a dispatch call, the store remembers the data for as long as the session is alive. I did not expect the store to forget it's state when i navigate from one page to another. As mentioned i folloed a pluralsight tutorial by cory-house and in that tutorial he did not use componentDidMount to call some data fetched from a mock sync call. He just hydrated the store on index.js and pass it via <Provider>. Could you enlighten me further?

Comment: React allows us to solve a problem in multiple ways, In your case Does your store remembers or not? you can check it by using [redux-dev-tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd?hl=en) just keep your dev tool open and check while navigating from another page

Comment: When i opened the dev-tool redux, my store still remembers the state

Comment: If your store remembers that means you need to deal with the lifecycle method to render data screen.

Comment: May I know which lifecycle method that is?